# Create csv file and pass It to backend call in React

Tags: reactjs, csv

I have a scenario where I want to create csv file and the same generated csv file I would like to pass It to backend call.
I can generate csv file using below plugin but would like to know how can I pass It to backend once file is generated?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-csv
Anyone please share the Idea on It?

Comment: Is the data coming from the backend? If so, why not create the CSV on the backend and supply React with a route to download it?

Comment: There are some functionalities given to user like he can select multiple contact numbers.I need to get all that numbers and need to create Its csv and pass that csv to backend call.

Comment: Personally, I would recommend you pass the information that the user wants in the CSV to the backend, create it there, and serve it back to the user. This covers all the requirements and could be done in a single request to the backend which replies with the CSV file itself.

Comment: The backend is the 3rd party API and It has the input parameter as these csv and som other too.
So I need to create csv at client side only and need to pass It to backend.
For example once user clicks on submit button,I like to create csv and call the backend API with csv as a input.